# How to read vertex_indices of a hookmodifier in python

Tags: modifiers

I have a BezierCurve with the handles hooked to two Empty's. After modifying the shape of the curve with the hooks, I want to apply the shape of the curve without removing the hooks from the modifierstack. So I can reshape the curve with the same hooks over and over again.

*Before applying shape in HookModifiers:*
[image]

*After appplying shape in HookModifiers:*
[image]

For each HookModifier I want to apply the shape of the curve and rehook the Empty via python. Therefore I need to know which vertices (control points and handles) were assigned to that hook.

With python, how can i get the vertices (control points and handles) that are attached to an object in the Hookmodifier?

In the blender API i found "bpy.types.HookModifier > vertex_indices" but I don't know how to use it.